# Synchronous sound playback from video source in VideoSourcePlayer control

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, aforge

I'm using the [Video Source Player control](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/bd272e5f-344c-56a5-f74f-1ac3062a9554.htm) from `AForge.Controls` to play a few video clips within a winforms application.

The code is something like this.

```
string fileName = @"C:\path\to\file.example";
videoSourcePlayer.VideoSource = new AForge.Video.AsyncVideoSource(new FileVideoSource(fileName), true);
videoSourcePlayer.Start();
```

The video file includes both audio and video streams, however as far I'm aware the control only handles video and not audio.

How can I then play the audio stream in a synchronous fashion with the video source player control?

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

The `Video Source Player control` has a event named `NewFrame`, which allows to determine the precise video position which could be useful to keep the audio being played synchronized with the video.

Comment: Why do you think it's ever possible using that control?

Comment: @Dmitry I'm not thinking it is possible using such control alone. I'm only looking for other alternative in which is possible to reproduce the audio contained the video file and somehow keep it synchronized with the video player control. If such method is too daunting then an alternative which is able to reproduce audio and video together (excluding embedded Windows Media Player) would be fine.

Comment: If the player doesn't play audio with video why are you using it? why not to replace it with another one? is is a viable option for you?

I checked the control and it doesn't have much control given to you as a user, for instance it doesn't fire when it start, stop or pause has been clicked on the control.

Comment: I've talked with some people and they say the same. Like it or not the project manager will have to allow the control to be replaced in the application if he wants audio enabled. Thank you all.

Comment: WPF's `MediaElement` is not an option? This seems like it'll do what you're looking for: http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/audio-video/how-to-creating-a-complete-audio-video-player/

Comment: Yes it is a working option. I've tried it and works. Could only try it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mentioned:

> I'm only looking for other alternative in which is possible to
>   reproduce the audio contained the video file and somehow keep it
>   synchronized with the video player control...

Maybe you can have a better luck by using a `ElementHost` and using WPF media control.

If this solution is eligible for you follow this steps:

1. Create a new WPF `UserControl` and add to your `WindowsForms` app.
2. In this `UserControl` add a media element and configure the way you want.
3. Build the solution.
4. Now in the toolbox must appear `YourSolutionName Controls` and you controls must be there.
5. Just drag it to your `WindowsForms` app and it must create an `ElementHost`.

I've created the `UserControl` as follow:

```
    <MediaElement Name="VideoMediaElement" 
                  Source="Media/Wildlife.wmv" 
                  LoadedBehavior="Manual"/>
```

Just remember in this example this file must be side-by-side with your app in a `Media` folder. If you miss this step it will give you the strange and not helpful error `0xC00D11B1`.

The loaded behavior `Manual` will give you the chance to control de video more freely.

After that you can do whathever you want in this `UserControl` like create `Play` and `Pause`:

```
    internal void Play()
    {
        this.VideoMediaElement.Play();
    }
```

And to access them in `WindowsForms` do this:

```
    private void WindowsFormsButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var videoControl = this.MyElementHost.Child as VideoUserControl;

        videoControl.Pause();
    }
```

Hope this helps. WPF MediaElement is much more easy to seach for than other libs.